# Improvements to handling serial linux terminal in C#

Tags: c#, terminal, serial-port, embedded-linux

I'm working on a project where I need to automate logging into a serial linux terminal in C#. I connect to the terminal via an FTDI cable.

I'm unable to connect to the linux terminal over network, so any SSH related methods are off the table.

Thanks in advance for the help!

My current solution involves using the SerialPort class to read each line from the serial terminal then checking that it contains key phrases (e.g does the input have "[HOSTNAME] login"? Does the input contain "root@[HOSTNAME]"?).

While this is *a* way of doing it, it's quite vunerable to changes or a line not outputting in an expected format and is generally not very elegant.

Are there better/more reliable ways to interact with a serial linux terminal? Are there any pre-exiting modules?

Comment: `man expect` (don't know if it exists natively in Windows). This is a bit of documentation: https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/. Here some C# sources (not an expert) that claims to support expect-like interface: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_Code/Library/Download_Telnet_and_Expect.htm.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, looking at expect it looks like you provide it a phrase and the function will wait for that to appear from a terminal. This is basically what I've managed to re-create in C# by string matching. I was wondering if there was an alternative method for knowing when a serial terminal is expecting a username/password or if login was successful etc.

Comment: In UNIX world it **is** `expect`, I am not a windows guy ;)

Comment: I didn't mention windows

Comment: But you didn't mention Mono either. :-)

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add @USER to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)